# Can not publish messages from RabbitMQ .NET Client

Tags: rabbitmq, publish, .net-core-3.1

I am trying to publish a message to a `RabbitMQ` queue and i just can't for some reason.
The `.NET RabbitMQ` client works when creating a `queue/exchange`, i can even bind...but publishing does not work.
I have tried publishing from the `CLI` and it works

```
 var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
 using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection()) {
    using (var channel = connection.CreateModel()) {
      channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchange: "e1", type: ExchangeType.Direct, durable: true, false);
      var declared = channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "qx", durable: true, true, false);
      channel.QueueBind("qx", "e1", "key");
    
    
      var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("something");
    
      var props = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
      props.Persistent = true;
    
      channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "e1", routingKey: "key", props, body: body);
     }
}
```

**P.S**
From the `CLI` i can see the queue getting created , getting binded , i can also create exchanges ...but not publishing.

Answer (score 0):

just created a quick console app and below works for me. Hope it helps

```
using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
       using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
       {
           channel.ExchangeDeclare("exchange_name", "fanout", false, false, null);
           string message = "";
           while (message != "end")
           {
               message = Console.ReadLine();
               var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
               channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "exchange_name",
                                    routingKey: "",
                                    basicProperties: null,
                                    body: body);
               Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0} type end to exit", message);
           }
           channel.Close();
       }
```

Comment: Did you declare no queue with no routing key and it worked? Because your code does not work for me.

Comment: yes when you are publishing to exchange you don't need queue.